# Does one get punished for not keeping positve mitzvos?

Tags: mitzvah, reward-punishment

Does one get punished for not keeping positive mitzvos? Or is it the case that you just do not get the reward for keeping them and punishments are for transgressing negative mitzvos?

Answer (score 1):

[Sharrei Teshuva 3:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shaarei_Teshuvah.3.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ועתה נדבר בענין עונש ביטול מצות עשה.
>
> אמרו רבותינו זכרונם לברכה אם הזהירו את האיש לעשות סוכה או לולב ואינו עושה מכין כו'.
>
> And now we will speak about the matter of punishment for the nullification of positive commandments:
>
> Our Rabbis, may their memory be blessed, said (Ketuvot 86b) [that] if [the court warned] someone to perform [the commandment of the] sukkah or [of the] palm branch (lulav) “and he does not do so, we strike, etc.”
>
> ואמרו כי האנשים אשר לא הניח על ראשם תפילין מעולם הם נקראים פושעי ישראל בגופן. ועונשם חמור מן העובר פעם אחת על חייבי כריתות. ואמרו כל שעונותיו מרובין מזכיותיו ובכללן עון פושעי ישראל בגופן כגון שלא הניח תפילין מעולם או עוברי עבירה כגון עריות. ליום הדין יורדין לגיהנם ונדונין שם י"ב חודש. לאחר י"ב חודש גופן כלה ונשמתן נשרפת ורוח מפזרתן תחת כפות רגלי הצדיקים שנאמר (מלאכי ג׳:כ״א) ועסותם רשעים כי יהיו אפר וגו'.
>
> And they said (Rosh Hashanah 17a) that men who have never placed tefillin on their heads are called “rebellious Jews with their bodies,” and their punishment is more severe than one who transgresses once against a sin for which he is liable for excision. And they said [that] all whose sins are greater than his merits and among [his sins] is the sin of rebellious Jews with their bodies - for example, one who has never worn tefillin or one who was involved in transgressions such as forbidden sexual relations - descend and are judged in Gehinnom for twelve months. After twelve months, their body is finished; and their soul is burnt; and the wind spreads it under the soles of the feet of the righteous ones, as it is stated (Malachi 3:21), “And you shall trample the wicked to a pulp, for they shall be dust, etc.”
>
> ואמרו מי שמקל (בעיניו) [בענין] מצות עשה כמו המבזה חולו של מועד שיש בו מצות עשה שנאמר (שמות כ״ג:ט״ו) את חג המצות תשמור. אף על פי שיש בידו תורה ומעשים טובים אין לו חלק לעולם הבא. ויש על כל מצות עשה אזהרת לאו כוללת שנאמר (דברים י״ג:א׳) לא תוסף עליו ולא תגרע ממנו:
>
> And they said (Sanhedrin 99a), [that] one who is permissive (in his eyes) [regarding] positive commandments, such as one who belittles the intermediate days of the festival - which is from a positive commandment, as it is stated (Exodus 23:15), “You shall observe the Feast of Matsot” - has no portion in the world to come, even if possesses Torah and good deeds. And there is a general warning of a negative commandment, for all the positive commandments - as it is stated (Deuteronomy 13:1), “neither add to it nor take away from it.”

Comment: Also, please see Rashi on Shemos 20:1. He brings proof from the Mechilta that HaShem metes out punishment when the Ten Commandments are not obeyed.